# How do I move a row between two rows in Numbers?

Tags: keyboard, iwork, numbers

Simple question. In iWork's Numbers, is there any way to move a row of data between two rows, as opposed to just plopping it on top of existing data? You can easily do this in Excel if you hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> key or some simliar combination when moving a row or even a group of rows.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the row in which you want your copied or cut (moved) line to be placed and select "**Insert**" from the menu bar and select "**Copied Rows**"

---

For something similar to a **key combo** you may want to try the following

1. <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> on the row you want to move your info to.
2. <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste your info to the new row.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click and release in the column header
2. Drag the column header. You'll see an insertion bar drawn between the destination columns.

[image]

You are probably moving the cursor over an edge of the selection rectangle until it turns into the hand and then dragging. That will replace the column you drag to.

[image]